# Как делать запросы в libCURL от другого IP, привязанному к серверу?

Tags: c++, curl

Есть несколько IPv4 привязанных к VDS. Есть софт (C++), который должен проводить HTTP запросы от этих IP через libCURL (C++). По аналогии с тем, как это делает:

```
ping -S привязанный_IP пингуемый_хост
```

Как это вообще делать можно из С++ + cURL?

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_INTERFACE.html

Comment: Дополнительные IP привязываются как "eth0:N" к основному eth0. Как думаете, приведённое решение сработает, если я будут указывать что-то вроде: "eth0:4"? К сожалению в настоящий момент далёк от VDS, не могу попробовать.

Comment: `The name can be an interface name, an IP address, or a host name.`

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curlhandle, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "198.51.100.88");
```

[Документация.](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_INTERFACE.html)